# argparse for conditionally optional argument

Tags: python, python-3.5, argparse

I have a script that have multiple usages depending on the arguments it receives. For example if called like:

```
script.py
```

it will execute its main function. But I also want it to be able to run other 
functions:

```
script.py -a
```

will enter an interactive mode.

```
script.py -r -f filename.txt
```

Should use a file to restart a shelve.

```
script.py -e -f filename.txt
```

Should use the file to extend the shelve.

My problem is that I want the -f flag to be optional, unless the -r or -e
flags are present.

My current code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("-a", action="store_true")
group.add_argument("-r", action="store_true")
group.add_argument("-e", action="store_true")
```

Now, I don't know how the -f flag fits in. I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: Ok. I see now that I don't really need the -f flag. I can make the -r and -e flags to store the file argument instead of boolean flags. But I would like to know if there is a way of having a flag be required only when another is required.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a

```
parser.add_argument('-f','--file',help='filename')
```

then a `-f filename` command will be accepted at all times and be present in the namespace as, e.g.

```
Namespace(file='filename', a=False, r=True, e=False)
```

if omitted, you'll see `file=None`.

One option is to just use that added information when given and needed, and ignore if you don't need it.  You might also want to give it a useful `default` value (for the cases where the users don't give you a name).

Another possibility is to define `-r` as

group.add_argument('-r', help='r mode filename')

Then instead of `args.r` being True/False, it will be `None/'filename'.

You may need to be more specific about what it means for the `filename` to be optional.  When is it option, required and/or prohibited.

You could also go the `subparsers` route, and define a `-f` argument for the `r` and 'e' subparsers, but not the 'a' one.

Pay attention also to what the usage/help looks like.  Think about how you want to instruct your user regarding correct usage.  Don't make it too complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My requirement is that the file be required only when the -r flag or the -e flags are present. Depending on the flag the file will be used differently. You said about the 'subparser' way, can you give an example of how I could do that?

Comment: And if they use the -a flag?  Is it ok to provide a filename, or do you want block it?  As for subparsers, start with the docs.  There's no 'mutually inclusive' grouping.